# Why does time incorrectly report such a fast time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I was playing around with big numbers, and wrote the following code:

```
import time

def ispow2(n):
    return not n & n - 1

start = time.clock()
ispow2(2**100000000)
end = time.clock()

print(end - start)
```

Surprisingly, this outputs `0.016864107385627148`, and insanely short amount of time. However, it actually takes about `8` seconds, not `0.02`.

Why is the time module reporting such a fast time when it clearly takes longer than that to run the code?

---

According to [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock), `clock()` is deprecated, so I switched it out for [`process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time). I get near identical results. Same with [`perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter).

---

Note: this is running from IDLE. When I ran from command line, the time seemed accurately reported. Perhaps pythonw.exe has something to do with this, but what?

However, when I add another `0` to the end of `2**10...`, it takes ~7 seconds on command line, but reported `0.1781140373572865`.

Comment: Even lesser on my machine. But it didn't take 8 seconds.

Comment: @thefourtheye It took ~8 seconds, most of which IDLE was not responding. Trying out CMD.

Comment: I'm seeing about 80 ms in the Python 2.7 interactive console, after wrapping your test up in a function. Interestingly, after pressing enter after the last line of the function, the console hung for a second or two... even though nothing was executing.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart exactly what I was seeing: the console hung for ~8 seconds.

Comment: for performance measurements you could use `from timeit import default_timer as timer`: it chooses the best timer for your platform, Python version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`python.exe` and `pythonw.exe` are optimizing the code before running. It seems that the `2**100000000` is being pre-computed. This small edit to the code:

```
import time

print("program entered")

def ispow2(n):
    return not n & n - 1

start = time.perf_counter()
ispow2(2**100000000)
end = time.perf_counter()

print(end - start)
```

Produces the following output completely after the wait:

```
program entered
0.01701506924359556
```

So the program doesn't even run until after the majority of the wait.

Data that suggests that this is with the `2**...` part (running from command line):

```
power of two|approximate wait time|reported time
1000000000  | 6  seconds          |0.1637752267742188
10000000000 | 62 seconds          |1.6400543291627092
```

On that last run, there was a clear ~`1.5` second wait between the output of `program entered` and `1.6400543291627092`.

Comment: [`PyCode_Optimize`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Python/peephole.c#l331) detects the bytecode pattern `LOAD_CONST`, `LOAD_CONST`, `BINOP`, and calls [`fold_binops_on_constants`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Python/peephole.c#l138) to evaluate the operation and replace it with a single `LOAD_CONST`. If you import the script, the module's code object is cached in the `__pycache__` directory, where you'll see that it's several megabytes, in agreement with `sys.getsizeof(2**100000000)`.

Answer (score 3):

The constant is precomputed:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 2**100)
1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (1267650600228229401496703205376)
            3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Compare:

```
$ ./python -mtimeit "2**1000"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0601 usec per loop
$ ./python -mtimeit "2**10000"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0584 usec per loop
```

vs.:

```
$ ./python -mtimeit -s "p=1000" "2**p"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.89 usec per loop
$ ./python -mtimeit -s "p=10000" "2**p"
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.2 usec per loop
```

In the first case the time doesn't change after increasing the power 10 times. It is changed as it should in the second case there the power is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to time small bits of code is with [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

If I use timeit on my computer and compare to yours, I get a similar number using Python 3.4:

```
import time
import timeit

def ispow2(n):
    return not n & n - 1

n=10

start = time.time()
for i in range(n):
    ispow2(2**100000000)
end = time.time()

print(end - start)

print(timeit.Timer('ispow2(2**100000000)', setup="from __main__ import ispow2").timeit(number=n))
```

Prints:

```
0.1257798671722412
0.12608672981150448
```

I used [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) vs [time.clock()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) but both seem to work.